# Trying to match Linux digest command in VB.NET or C#

Tags: .net, sha1

What would be the equivalent code in C# or VB.net that would match the following Linux command?

echo -n "%s" | openssl dgst -sha1

I tried the following VB.NET code, but results don't match.

```
  Dim abPassword() As Byte
  Dim abPasswordHashed() As Byte
  Dim clSha As SHA1Managed = New SHA1Managed()
  Dim strHexPassword As String
  Dim strPassword As String 
  Dim strPasswordHashed As String

  ' strPassword assigned with a value ...
  abPassword = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strPassword)
  strHexPassword = BitConverter.ToString(abPassword)
  strHexPassword = strHexPassword.Replace("-", "")
  abPassword = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strHexPassword)
  abPasswordHashed = clSha.ComputeHash(abPassword)
  strPasswordHashed = BitConverter.ToString(abPasswordHashed)
  strPasswordHashed = strPasswordHashed.Replace("-", "")
```

The string I'm trying to match contains 40 hexadecimal digits and so does my result, but they are different.

Comment: This looks like you're converting the password to hex and then hashing the hex in VB, rather than just hashing the password? What happens if you remove the four lines that use strHexPassword?

Comment: That worked, thanks!